# Need solving issues with Makefile for reading in Storm data program

Tags: c++, makefile

I have to create a program to read in a Storm.dat file (contains ocean storms and generates brief reports).  I have made the neccessary files but I am running into some issue with the Makefile.

Below is my code:

storm.h

```
#ifndef STORMS_H
#define STORMS_H

class Storm
{
private:
    char where; // A, E, C
    char name[11]; // recall '\0'
    int seq; // sequence num 1...
    int year;
    int max_wind; // knots
    int min_press; // millibars or 10000 //
    char type; // H, S, D
public:
    Storm() ;// default constructor
    void print() const ;

    //5 accessors are code next..
    int get_seq() const;
    int get_year() const;
    int get_max_wind() const;
    int get_min_press() const;
    char get_type() const;

} ;

#endif
```

storm.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // re. setw, etc...
#include <cstring> // re. strcpy( dest, sorc ); etc... //
#include <cstdlib> // re. atoi

#include "storm.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::setw;
using std::left;
using std::right;

 const char* BASINS[] = { " ", "Atlantic", "Eastern Pacific", "Central Pacific" };

int i_basin( char c )
{
    if( c == 'A' ) return 1;
    if( c == 'E' ) return 2;
    if( c == 'C' ) return 3;
    return 0;
}

const char* TYPES[] = { " ", "Hurricane", "Storm", "Depression" };

int i_type( char c )
{
    if( c == 'H' ) return 1;
    if( c == 'S' ) return 2;
    if( c == 'D' ) return 3;
    return 0;
}

Storm::Storm() // default constructor
: where('N'), seq(0), year(0), max_wind(0), min_press(0), type('N')
{ strcpy( name, "None" ); }

void Storm::print() const
{   
    cout << left << setw(17) << BASINS[i_basin(where)]
         << setw(19) << TYPES[i_type(type)]
         << setw(11) << name
         << right << setw(2) << seq
         << '/' << year
         << setw(8) << max_wind;
    if( min_press )
        cout << setw(6) << min_press;
    cout << endl;
}

//5 accessors are coded here...
int Storm::get_seq() const { return seq; }
int Storm::get_year() const { return year; }
int Storm::get_max_wind() const { return max_wind; }
int Storm::get_min_press() const { return min_press; }
char Storm::get_type() const { return type; }
```

assign3_class_storm.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "storm.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::flush;
using std::cin;
using std::ios;

const char* HEADER =
    "Storm                               Name         Date     Wind  mbar\n"
    "--------------------------------------------------------------------\n";

const char* FNAME_BIN = "storm.dat";


typedef std::vector< Storm > Storms;

bool loadBinFile( const char* fname, Storms& vStorms ) ;
void showStorms( const Storms& vStorms );

template< typename T, typename Cmp >
void sel_sort( std::vector< T >& data, Cmp myCmp  );

// re. sort by increasing dates & seq...
int cmpByYear( const Storm& a, const Storm& b );
// re. sort by decreasing wind speed.
int cmpByWind( const Storm& a, const Storm& b );
// re. sort by increasing air pressure.
int cmpByPress( const Storm& a, const Storm& b );


int main() 
{
    Storms sList;
    if( loadBinFile( FNAME_BIN, sList ) )
    {
        cout << "Now showing sList loaded from file "
             << FNAME_BIN << endl;
        showStorms( sList );


        sel_sort( sList, cmpByYear);
        cout <<"\nSorted by dates ... \n";
        //showStorms( sList );

        sel_sort( sList, cmpByWind );
        cout <<"\nSorted by decreasing wind speed ... \n";
        //showStorms( sList );

        sel_sort( sList, cmpByPress );
        cout <<"\nSorted by increasing air pressure ... \n";
        //showStorms( sList );
    }


    cout << "Press 'Enter' to continue/exit ... " << flush;
    cin.get();

}

void showStorms( const Storms& vStorms )
{
    cout << "Total storms here is: " << vStorms.size() << endl;
    cout << HEADER;
    size_t i = 0;
    while(  i < vStorms.size()  )
    {
        vStorms[i].print();
        ++i;
        if( i % 20 == 0 )
        {
            cout << endl;

            cout << "Press 'Enter' to continue ... " << flush;
            cin.get();

            if( i != vStorms.size() )
                cout << HEADER;
        }
    }
}

bool loadBinFile( const char* fname, Storms& vStorms )
{
    fstream fs ;
    fs.open( fname, ios::in | ios::binary );
    if( fs )
    {
        Storm tmp;
        while( fs.read( (char*)&tmp, sizeof(Storm) ) )
            vStorms.push_back( tmp );
        fs.close();
        return true;
    }
    cout << "\nThere was a problem opening file "
              << fname << endl;
    return false;
}


template< typename T, typename Cmp >
void sel_sort( std::vector< T >& data, Cmp myCmp  )
{
    int len = data.size();
    int lenMinusOne = len-1;
    for( int j = 0; j <  lenMinusOne; ++ j )
    {
        int index_min = j;
        for( int i = j+1; i < len; ++ i )
            if(  myCmp(data[i], data[index_min] ) < 0 )
                index_min = i;
        // now swap ...
        T tmp = data[j];
        data[j] = data[index_min];
        data[index_min] = tmp;
    }
}


// re. sort by increasing dates & seq...
int cmpByYear( const Storm& a, const Storm& b )
{
    int cmp = a.get_year() - b.get_year();
    if( cmp == 0 )
        return a.get_seq() - b.get_seq();
    return cmp;
}

// re. sort by decreasing wind speed.
int cmpByWind( const Storm& a, const Storm& b )
{
    return b.get_max_wind() - a.get_max_wind();
}
// re. sort by increasing air pressure.
int cmpByPress( const Storm& a, const Storm& b )
{
    return a.get_min_press() - b.get_min_press();
}
```

If anyone can help me figure out these errors I am getting when I create the Makefile:

here is my Makefile

```
output: assign3_class_storm.o storm.o
    g++ -o assign3_class_storm assign3_class_storm.o
    g++ -o storm storm.o

storm.o: storm.cc storm.h
    g++ -c storm.cc

assign3_class_storm.o: assign3_class_storm.cc storm.h
    g++ -c assign3_class_storm.cc

clean:
    -rm *.o assign3_class_storm storm
```

The errors I'm getting:

```
g++ -c assign3_class_storm.cc
g++ -c storm.cc
g++ -o assign3_class_storm assign3_class_storm.o
assign3_class_storm.o: In function `showStorms(std::vector<Storm, std::allocator<Storm> > const&)':
assign3_class_storm.cc:(.text+0x1a2): undefined reference to `Storm::print() const'
assign3_class_storm.o: In function `loadBinFile(char const*, std::vector<Storm, std::allocator<Storm> >&)':
assign3_class_storm.cc:(.text+0x2db): undefined reference to `Storm::Storm()'
assign3_class_storm.o: In function `cmpByYear(Storm const&, Storm const&)':
assign3_class_storm.cc:(.text+0x3d6): undefined reference to `Storm::get_year() const'
assign3_class_storm.cc:(.text+0x3e4): undefined reference to `Storm::get_year() const'
assign3_class_storm.cc:(.text+0x3fd): undefined reference to `Storm::get_seq() const'
assign3_class_storm.cc:(.text+0x40b): undefined reference to `Storm::get_seq() const'
assign3_class_storm.o: In function `cmpByWind(Storm const&, Storm const&)':
assign3_class_storm.cc:(.text+0x438): undefined reference to `Storm::get_max_wind() const'
assign3_class_storm.cc:(.text+0x446): undefined reference to `Storm::get_max_wind() const'
assign3_class_storm.o: In function `cmpByPress(Storm const&, Storm const&)':
assign3_class_storm.cc:(.text+0x46e): undefined reference to `Storm::get_min_press() const'
assign3_class_storm.cc:(.text+0x47c): undefined reference to `Storm::get_min_press() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'output' failed
make: *** [output] Error 1
```

If anyone can help me fix this, I would really appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the executable to be called `storm` or `assign3_class_storm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your makefile is set up to build *two* executables, `storm` and `assign3_class_storm`. This makes no sense; you can't build `storm` because there's no `main()` in `storm.cc`, and you can't build `assign3_class_storm` from `assign3_class_storm.cc` alone, because it relies on functions of the `Storm` class, which is defined in `storm.cc`.

First let's correct the central problem:

```
output: assign3_class_storm.o storm.o
    g++ -o storm assign3_class_storm.o storm.o
```

Once that works perfectly(*), you can improve it by making the name of the product the name of the rule (so that Make will know that the rule need not be executed when the file already exists and is up to date):

```
storm: assign3_class_storm.o storm.o
    g++ -o storm assign3_class_storm.o storm.o
```

Once that works perfectly, you can make this rule less redundant with [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
storm: assign3_class_storm.o storm.o
    g++ -o $@ $^
```

And then if you like you can make the output more concise:

```
storm: assign3_class_storm.o storm.o
    @echo building $@...
    @g++ -o $@ $^
```

(*)You might have to correct a small omission in `assign3_class_storm.cc`.

Comment: I got it working thanks but quick question, when I run the executable, I can read the data from the storm.dat file but none of my sorts work.

Comment: @user3325133: 1) That's a separate question you should ask as a separate question, 2) at a glance, I don't see anything wrong with your sorting code, but I'm not going to look any further, because 3) you haven't given an example I can try (because you haven't provided the data file that produces the error) and it's complex enough that it would take considerable effort to fill in the blanks, which leads straight to 4) the [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as the gold standard of what to put in a question-- and a vital programming skill.

Comment: Thanks for your help with the Makefile

Comment: how do I add the storm.dat file into the question, The file is big with 2700 entries.

Comment: Does the sorting error appear with 2699 entries? How about 2 entries? How about if you simplify the `Storm` structure, maybe cut it down to a single `int`? See the link I gave above.